# How can I build the modal by default at the bottom in React Native?

Tags: user-interface, react-native, interface-builder

I'm working on a project about React-Native and look forward to building a screen with the same interface as below:

https://dribbble.com/shots/4697740-Skate-Spot-Detail

Answer (score 1):

What's is problem actually? If you want to develop a popup/modal like screens then you have to use ***import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'*** and ***Routes*** to navigate between different components/screens.

Comment: You should ask as a comment

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of a question requesting for resources on using animations in React Native.

To achieve what you want you'll want to use the `Animated` component within the `react-native` library, here's a pretty good tutorial to get what you want: https://rationalappdev.com/movie-tickets-booking-app-with-react-native/

You can of course find a library within NPM that will do the job for you but I would recommend learning how to make these components yourself to understand it better.